# Generate SOAP Web Service client forms (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, code-generation, client

I have a Web Service accessible via SOAP. Let's assume it provides a method with the signature

```
sayHello(String name)
```

Of course, I have the WSDL describing the Web Service.

What I want to do now is to generate a client web application (war archive) with a GUI that provides a form to enter the parameter for the Web Service method. In case of the example, the form must just allow to enter the value for the "name" parameter. Then, a SOAP message must be assembled and sent to the WS.

Is there any way or any framework to generate such a webapp **automatically**!? The actual kind of the resulting webapp is not important, it may be a GWT webapp, JSF, plain Servlet with JSP or whatever. Even a plain HTML/JavaScript client app would be OK.

I mean, there are tools to generate CRUD forms out of data models, so there must be tools to create forms for Web Services, too...

I've been googling around for a long time, but the only thing I've found is a feature of Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/WebServiceClient.html . Basically, this does what I want, but I'm looking for a more ..hm.. elegant way to do this ;-)

Thanks in advance,

Frank

Comment: AFAIK oracle application servers automatically generate a simple html form to invoke such webservices, when you open the service in a browser.

Comment: Same for GlassFish where you can find it under `http://.../YourService?tester`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Btw, I'm using JBoss AS 6 (the Web Service is a JAX-WS annotated Statless Session Bean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is (I think) similar to what this site seems to do:  [link soaptest](http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html)

As far as I know there is no framework that supports this out of the box.
All frameworks support the automatic generation of client stubs and artifacts and application developers use that to implement their functionality.
In your case create the HTML interface your self to test the web service.
Only .NET web services provide similar tool for testing [link text](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp#OLE_LINK3)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Netbeans provides simple web pages to test the functionality of web services methods (methods offered by the server). You can find a decent amount of guides showing you how to create wevservice clients on youtube. It is a relatively straight forward process.

Comment: Hm yes, but I'm looking for a way that is independent of any IDE and can (maybe) be integrated in the Maven build process. So ideally, I'm looking for a command promt like Axis2's wsdl2java - "wsdl2webform" :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for testing the web service: go for [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). It's a standalone application and (to my opinion) a must for every SOAP engineer.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it's not for testing purposes. Instead, it's a kind of administration interface so it must be accessible in a very easy way.